# Visual Studio 2022 Android Device Manager - Emulator device setup "The decryption operation failed, see inner exception."

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2022, maui, android-device-manager

Just installed Visual Studio Community 2022 on Windows 10 and started a basic hello world Maui template, tried to run it on the Android emulator, followed the directions from a website to setup a new Android emulator virtual device.  After it downloads, I get the decryption error in the screenshot.  If I try again it starts over re-downloading it for a while then gives the same decryption error.  This also happens when I tried downloading some of the other Android device images too.

Only post I can find on this topic is from a few years ago for the VS 2019 version with a reply saying the "problem was identified" and a fix was in an update.  Apparently, not correct.  Is there some something else I need to install?  An SDK or anything to get the device image decrypted?  Or maybe a way to manually setup the image?

Also, how do I even SEE the "inner exception" for the Android device manager?  Nothing appears on the main VS window, where normal build errors occur.

Visual Studio 2022 Android Device Manager error "The decryption operation failed, see inner exception."

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggXI1.jpg)

Comment: FYI, Still no fix found.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps:

1.[Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows) correctly;

2.delete the old emulator and create a new one, then try again;

3.If the problem persists, try to repair your visual studio.
For more details, check document: [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) .

Comment: Nope, doesn't fix it.

Comment: You can try to reinstall your visual studio. For more information, check: [Install Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 0):

#### Downloading New Emulators... is confusing:[image: Downloading New Emulator]

#### It takes you here and that is not what I was looking for:

[image: SDK Page]

#### This post's step 1 is what I was looking for: [image]

#### Hope this helps!

> ##### Reference Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73842543/8122581